# Need to close the side panel on browser back button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, dom-events

I build an app and there are several side-panel opening scenarios so I was able to implement all the functionalities

- Open
- Close
- SetContent
- etc..

When I tested it I realize that the side panel is not closing when the browser back button clicked. If anyone can help me with this issue it would be really helpful.

I used react and context-api concept to get the work done.

Comment: How do you handle navigation ? You could add a navigation hook autoclosing the panel when the location changes.

Comment: @known-as-bmf I use react-router

Comment: So, only certain routes should display certain side panels?

Comment: Yeah, exactly side panel should show up on a certain route